# Plot the break of Highrange of a MACD

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

hello can someone help me plotshape whenever a MACD high is broken like this?

this is my code

```
//@version=5
indicator("break high", overlay = true)

// === MACD ===
fastMA = input.int(title="Fast moving average",  defval = 12, minval = 7)
slowMA = input.int(title="Slow moving average",  defval = 26, minval = 7)
signalLength = input.int(9, minval=1)
MacdControl = input(true, title="MACD/Histogram Control")

[currMacd,,] = ta.macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, signalLength)
[prevMacd,,] = ta.macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, signalLength)
signal = ta.ema(currMacd, signalLength)
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9) //Zero Line


crossoverbull = ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine)
crossoverbear = ta.crossover(signalLine, macdLine)


var can_find = false
condstart = crossoverbull
condstop = crossoverbear

can_find := condstop ? false : condstart ? true : can_find

var float highesthigh = na

highesthigh := if (condstart)
    high
else if (can_find)
    if (high > highesthigh)
        high
    else
        highesthigh
else
    na

plot(highesthigh, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXIPK.png)

I dont know hot to store the revious high to be referenced when a cande breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage few functions to achieve this.

First, let's declare a variable that will store previous `highesthigh` and use the `var` keyword so that it's value won't reset between bars/executions:

```
var float lastHighestHigh = na
```

Second, we'll want to reset this variable each time we get into new `highesthigh` calculations so we'll need a `bool` variable to check for this condition. We can simply check if current bar is not `na` and if previous bar had `na` value for `highesthigh`:

```
firstBarAfterHH = not na(highesthigh) and na(highesthigh[1])
```

Third, we'll check for the value of `highesthigh` last time it wasn't `na` using the `ta.valuewhen()` function. We'll have to call it on each bar for consistency:

```
valueOfLastHighestHigh = ta.valuewhen(not na(highesthigh), highesthigh, 1)
```

Fourth, we'll set the value of our `lastHighestHigh` variable so it will get the value of `valueOfLastHighestHigh` each time we `firstBarAfterHH` is `true`:

```
if firstBarAfterHH
    lastHighestHigh := valueOfLastHighestHigh
```

At this point, we have 2 variables we can work with:

1. `highesthigh` - which will store the current bar highest high.
2. `lastHighestHigh` - which will store our previous `highesthigh`.

So we can compare them using `ta.crossover()` function to get the first bar when one value is over the other. For example:

```
plotshape(ta.crossover(highesthigh, lastHighestHigh))
```

Full code:

```
var float lastHighestHigh = na
firstBarAfterHH = not na(highesthigh) and na(highesthigh[1])
valueOfLastHighestHigh = ta.valuewhen(not na(highesthigh), highesthigh, 1)

if firstBarAfterHH
    lastHighestHigh := valueOfLastHighestHigh

plotshape(ta.crossover(highesthigh, lastHighestHigh))
```